# Adding a new Run Configuration for Android Application in Android Studio not possible

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to add a new Run Configuration to an existing Android Project (Run -> Edit Configurations ...). When I click on Android Application in the Template section the dialog does not change:

[image: Edit Configuration Screenshot]

I also get an IDE Fatal error with the following stack trace (only the beginning):

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/tools/idea/run/activity/StartActivityFlagsProvider
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.AndroidRunConfigurationType$AndroidRunConfigurationFactory.createTemplateConfiguration(AndroidRunConfigurationType.java:45)
    at com.intellij.execution.configurations.ConfigurationFactory.createTemplateConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:64)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.RunManagerImpl.createTemplateSettings$intellij_platform_lang_impl(RunManagerImpl.kt:260)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.RunManagerImpl.getConfigurationTemplate(RunManagerImpl.kt:252)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.RunConfigurable.showTemplateConfigurable(RunConfigurable.kt:322)
```

**Update 24.03.2019:**

This problem also appears when I am creating a new project from a template.

When I load a project the event log looks  like the following:

```
10:21   Gradle sync started
10:21   Project setup started
10:21   Gradle sync finished in 2 s 333 ms (from cached state)
10:21   Gradle sync failed: setup project failed: com/android/tools/idea/run/activity/StartActivityFlagsProvider (2 s 561 ms)
```

Comment: i don't see this issue in Android studio 3.3. Which android studio version you are using?

Comment: I am using the latest release Android Studio 3.3.2. The problem also appears with a complete new template project.